# What javascript dependency management solutions are available for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What javascript dependency management solutions are available for Rails? And what are their relative pros/cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you checked here:
http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/javascript_tools.html

I think sprockets is the most commonly used, but juicer does all your frontend files like css as well.